# css print repeat headers on subsequent pages

Tags: css, page-break, print-preview

I have searched and viewed so many similar questions but can not solve this issue yet . I've tried `page-break-before: always;` but seems it doesn't work neither ff nor chrome . all suggestions are welcome

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @NikosM i want to repeat thead on sebsequent pages and tried page-break-befor and page-break-afer in my css , but it doesn't work

Comment: still not clear repeat `thead` on pages?? can you add an example?

Comment: as i said , i want to repeat `thead` of table on subsequent pages when i wanna `print` page . in print preview and print result , i need headers repeating on page breaks;

Comment: want to make table header fixed? can be done but not on subsequent pages

Comment: for only css solution you will need to add extra headers and show/hide them on pages (with extra css used only for printing, `media=print`)

Comment: how can i count number of pages in print preview to add headers ?

Comment: yeap i dont think its doable with css only, you could try to add headers not shown and display them only on page breaks, but it might not work